# How to fix 'Nullable object must have a value' for a string using TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am checking to see if a user has payment data associated with them and to display that data if so.

I've tried redefining 'paymentMessage' in various ways to no avail. I am getting the error that paymentMessage must have a value.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
  string paymentMessage = (string)TempData["payment_result"];
  PublicBasicDetailsViewModel viewModel = new PublicBasicDetailsViewModel();
  viewModel.Patron = Datasource.GetPatron(CurrentUser.PatronId.Value);
  viewModel.Transactions = Datasource.GetPatronTransactionList(viewModel.Patron.PatronID);
  viewModel.IsFirstLogin = CurrentUser.IsFirstLogin;

  if (CurrentUser.IsFirstLogin) {
    string userIdent = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    Datasource.SetFirstLogin(userIdent);
  }

  if (paymentMessage == null) {
    viewModel.HasPaymentResult = false;
    return View(viewModel);
  }

  else if (paymentMessage == "SUCCESS") {
    viewModel.HasPaymentResult = true;
    return View(viewModel);
  }

  else {
   viewModel.HasPaymentResult = true;
   viewModel.Errors = paymentMessage;
   return View(viewModel);
  }
}
```

This is the error message appearing when I log in as a user

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object
>   must have a value.
>
> Source Error: Line 57: string paymentMessage =
>   (string)TempData["payment_result"];

Comment: Run the code until the exception occurs. When it occurs, go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?TempData["payment_result"]` What is shown there? What about for `?TempData["payment_result"].GetType()`?

Comment: Thank you, turned out CurrentUser.PatronID didn't exist for this user. Silly mistake. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why `string paymentMessage = (string)TempData["payment_result"];` throws an exception.

Comment: So for some reason Chrome was telling me it was that line that was the problem. However, the issue seems to be coming from the line: viewModel.Patron = Datasource.GetPatron(CurrentUser.PatronId.Value); When that has a null value, the rest of the code won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Tempdata has a lifetime of two actions.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/827059/Data-Passing-Mechanism-in-MVC-Architecture